Python cannot find ginsim and biolqm, how do i fix this?
I have a project that uses these packages in a program, however when I try to run the program python cannot seem to find the packages. These packages are part of the colomoto tool box. I have put the code i am trying to execute below
import ginsim
import biolqm
import maboss
import pypint
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd # for the visualization of lists of states
from colomoto_jupyter import tabulate # for fixpoint table display
from itertools import combinations  # for iterating over sets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for modifying plots

When trying this i got this error:
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import ginsim
      2 import biolqm
      3 import maboss

File E:\project\bioenv\lib\site-packages\ginsim\__init__.py:6
      3 import re
      4 import sys
----> 6 import biolqm
      8 from colomoto_jupyter import *
      9 from colomoto_jupyter.sessionfiles import new_output_file

File E:\project\bioenv\lib\site-packages\biolqm\__init__.py:13
     10 import pandas as pd
     11 import numpy as np
---> 13 from ginsim.gateway import japi, restart
     14 from ginsim.state import *
     16 from py4j.java_gateway import JavaObject

File E:\project\bioenv\lib\site-packages\ginsim\gateway.py:61
     58     if __env:
     59         module._japi_start()
---> 61 start()
     62 atexit.register(stop)

File E:\project\bioenv\lib\site-packages\ginsim\gateway.py:26, in start()
     24 def start():
     25     assert (not __env)
---> 26     __env["proc"] = subprocess.Popen(["GINsim", "-py"], \
     27                         stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
     28     port = int(__env["proc"].stdout.readline().strip())
     30     # start the gateway and return the entry point (GINsim's ScriptLauncher)

File E:\project\bioenv\lib\subprocess.py:858, in Popen.__init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    854         if self.text_mode:
    855             self.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(self.stderr,
    856                     encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
--> 858     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    859                         pass_fds, cwd, env,
    860                         startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
    861                         p2cread, p2cwrite,
    862                         c2pread, c2pwrite,
    863                         errread, errwrite,
    864                         restore_signals, start_new_session)
    865 except:
    866     # Cleanup if the child failed starting.
    867     for f in filter(None, (self.stdin, self.stdout, self.stderr)):

File E:\project\bioenv\lib\subprocess.py:1327, in Popen._execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1325 # Start the process
   1326 try:
-> 1327     hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1328                              # no special security
   1329                              None, None,
   1330                              int(not close_fds),
   1331                              creationflags,
   1332                              env,
   1333                              cwd,
   1334                              startupinfo)
   1335 finally:
   1336     # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe
   1337     # handles that only the child should have open.  You need
   (...)
   1340     # pipe will not close when the child process exits and the
   1341     # ReadFile will hang.
   1342     self._close_pipe_fds(p2cread, p2cwrite,
   1343                          c2pread, c2pwrite,
   1344                          errread, errwrite)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified


As per previous suggestions, I made an Environment in miniconda called bioenv and used ipykernel to use that environment as a kernel in jupyter. I still get the same error. I installed all the necessary packages in that environment.

Command to install the packages:
conda install -c colomoto -c bioconda -c conda-forge -c potassco ginsim-python



I have also tried changing the PATH variable according to CHATGPT but that has not led me anywhere. GINsim runs normally as a .jar file which I installed from the official website.

I would love to know what is going on and a fix to this problem. Thank you.

The problem is that it can't find the GINsim executable.  Either you didn't install it, or you didn't add it to your PATH environment variable.

Are you able to run GINsim from a command window?
